# Importing variables and mixins from the Storybook to another project

Tags: sass, storybook

For my project I'm using a Storybook for components. In there, I defined variables and mixins I consume everywhere in the Storybook for standardization.

I would like to import these variables and mixins in my other projects where I'm consuming Storybook, but unfortunately I'm not giving the key.

I tried a few things with no success.

Has someone solved this issue and can help me?
Thanks!